# How to hide suggested posts on LinkedIn?

Tags: google-chrome, linkedin, google-chrome-extensions, css, user-stylesheets

Suddenly my feed on LinkedIn is full of "Suggested Posts" that I've no interest in. How do I hide them?

The support page only recommends selecting "I don't like this subject" or "I don't like this author" but I want to get rid of them completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's currently possible to hide the suggested posts using user CSS, which you can apply with extensions like [Stylus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylus/clngdbkpkpeebahjckkjfobafhncgmne).

This CSS hides all suggested posts:

```
div:has(> div > div > div > div > .update-components-header--with-control-menu-and-hide-post) {
    display: none;
}
```

The CSS is likely to break in the future and will require regular maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

Settings & privacy > Account preferences > General preferences > Feed preferences > Most recent posts